# Prove that the complement of A intersection B is equal to the union of the complement of A and B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I'm just learning how to write proofs in math, and I'm currently trying to prove this equality:
$$ \overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} $$

My thinking is to use the definition of intersection:
let $u \in U$, such that $u \in A \cap B$. By the definition of intersection, we know that this is the same as saying $u \in A$ and $u \in B$. Thus,

$ \neg (u \in A\cap B) \Leftrightarrow \neg(u \in A$ and $ u\in B)$,

we obtain

$u \notin A \cap B \Leftrightarrow u \notin$ A or $u\notin B$.

Which is the same as saying, $ \overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} $.

I feel like my proof is wrong since it feels like I'm only describing the equality, rather than proving it? Any tips or explanation of the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you really understand what you wrote in words then you've no problem: it is accurate, and perhaps the most important step is that denying "and" leads us to use "or", and the other way around. Nice.

Comment: Actually, your proof is ok, as is.  An alternative approach is to use the general method of showing that sets $E$ and $F$ are equal, which is to show that $E \subseteq F$ and $F \subseteq E$.  Then, to show that $E \subseteq F$, you start with the assumption that $x \in E$, and then deduce that therefore $x$ must be in $F$.

Comment: Using $\overline A$ for the complement is a bad idea, since that already means something else (the _closure_ of $A$). A better notation might be $A^c$ (`A^c`)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we can prove the following two equations.

1. $$\left(\bigcup_{n} S_{n}\right)^{c}=\bigcap_{n} S_{n}^{c}$$
2. $$\left(\bigcap_{n} S_{n}\right)^{c}=\bigcup_{n} S_{n}^{c}$$

where the $c$ represents the complementary set.

Now let's prove the first formula:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\text { Step 1: } x \in \left(\bigcup_{n} S_{n}\right)^{c} ，\forall x  \\
&\Rightarrow x \in S_{1}^{c} \quad x \in S_{2}^{c} \quad \ldots \quad x \in S_{n}^{c} \\
&\Rightarrow x \notin \bigcup_{n} S_{n}=S_{1} \cup S_{2} \ldots \cup S_{n}\\
&\Rightarrow x \notin S_{1} \quad x \notin S_{2} \quad \ldots \quad x \notin S_{n} \\
&\Rightarrow x \in S_{1}^{c} \quad x \in S_{2}^{c} \quad \ldots \quad x \in S_{n}^{c} \\
&\Rightarrow x \in S_{1}^{c} \cap S_{2}^{c} \ldots \cap S_{n}^{c}=\bigcap_{n} S_{n}^{c}=\text { RHS }\\
&\text { i.e. , } \left(\bigcup_{n} S_{n}\right)^{c} \subset \bigcap_{n} S_{n}^{c}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\text { Step 2: } x \in \bigcap_{n} S_{n}^{c}=S_{1}^{c} \cap S_{2}^{c} \ldots \cap S_{n}^{c} ，\forall x  \\
&\Rightarrow x \in S_{1}^{c} \quad x \in S_{2}^{c} \quad \ldots \quad x \in S_{n}^{c} \\
&\Rightarrow x \notin S_{1} \quad x \notin S_{2} \quad \ldots \quad x \notin S_{n} \\
&\Rightarrow x \notin S_{1} \cup S_{2} \ldots \cup S_{n}=\bigcup_{n} S_{n} \\
&\Rightarrow x \in\left(\bigcup_{n} S_{n}\right)^{c}=\text { LHS } \\
&\text { i.e. , } \bigcap_{n} S_{n}^{c} \subset\left(\bigcup_{n} S_{n}\right)^{c}
\end{aligned}
$$

Based on the results of the above two steps, the first formula is valid.

The proof of the second formula is similar to the above.

In particular, when $n=2$, the conclusion required in the question can be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the properties and concepts involved, one gets

\begin{align*}
\overline{A\cap B} & = \overline{\{x\in U : x\in A\}\cap\{x\in U : x\in B\}}\\\\
& = \overline{\{x\in U : (x\in A)\wedge(x\in B)\}}\\\\
& = \{x\in U : \neg((x\in A)\wedge(x\in B))\}\\\\
& = \{x\in U : \neg(x\in A)\vee\neg(x\in B)\}\\\\
& = \{x\in U : x\not\in A\vee x\not\in B\}\\\\
& = \{x\in U : x\not\in A\}\cup\{x\in U : x\not\in B\}\\\\
& = \overline{A}\cup\overline{B}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!